# Scala Function Filtering Field for Only Numbers

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following functions:

```
  def isAllDigits(x: String) = x forall Character.isDigit

  def filterNum(x: (Int, String)) : Boolean = {
    accumNum.add(1)
    if(isAllDigits(x._2)) false
    else true
  }
```

I am passing in key/value's and I want to check that the values are numeric. For some reason it is filtering out :

```
res10: Array[(Int, String)] = Array((1,18964), (2,39612), (3,1), (4,""), (5,""), (6,""), (7,""), (8,""), (9,1), (10,""))
```

but allowing this:

```
res9: Array[(Int, String)] = Array((18,1000.0), (22,23.99), (18,1001.0), (22,23.99), (18,300.0), (22,23.99), (18,300.0), (22,23.99), (18,300.0), (22,23.99))
```

Does .isDigit only allow doubles? But I am confused as to why when x is (Int,String) the double/int being passed in is being seen as a string.

Edit:
I am using this function in Spark with the following:

```
val numFilterRDD = numRDD.filter(filterNum)
```

numRDD.take() example:

```
res11: Array[(Int, String)] = Array((1,18964), (2,39612), (3,1), (4,""), (5,""), (6,""), (7,""), (8,""), (9,1), (10,""), (11,""), (16,""), (18,1000.0), (19,""), (20,""), (21,""), (22,23.99), (23,""), (24,""), (25,""))
```

Comment: Could you provide some example how you use this filterNum function?

Comment: I dont know if this is just a typo but notice that that elements of res10 are not of type (Int, String) but (Any, String). This should not even compile.

Comment: Added additional context.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are running through each character separately. So, in the case of a double, it gets to the point that the decimal is checked and that by itself is not a number:

```
Character.isDigit('.') //false
```

You might be better to use a regex.

```
x matches """^\d+(\.?\d+)$"""
```

Comment: Thanks, Regex is a bit off for what I was going for but here is what worked for me: def isAllDigits(x: String) = x matches """^\d{1,}\.*\d*$"""